# Некоторые вопросы по БЭМ

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, бэм

Читаю БЭМ и появились некоторые вопросы:

"Блок не должен влиять на свое окружение, т. е. блоку не следует задавать внешнюю геометрию (в виде отступов, границ, влияющих на размеры) и позиционирование". Т.е. я не имею права пользоваться такими вещами для блока как margin, padding, border, position, float и т.д.???

Каким образом тогда их так просто и красиво меняют местами в примерах? 
https://ru.bem.info/methodology/key-concepts/ раздел "Свободное перемещение".

Дают красивый пример с блоком Head block внутри которого очень легко и не принужденно двигают еще 3 блока logo, search, auth. "Так, например, логотип и форму авторизации можно поменять местами. При этом вносить изменения в CSS или JavaScript-код блока не нужно." - сказано в примере.

Но с точки зрения HTML мы имеем следующий код

```html
<div class="headblock">
    <div class="logoblock"></div>
    <div class="searchblock"></div>
    <div class="authblock"></div>
</div>
```

(все отлично, все красиво. Мы имеем блок в который вложены другие блоки)

А если в css у этих блоков будут установлены float? Как без изменения css поменять эти блоки местами в таком случае?

Comment: `Т.е. я не имею права пользоваться такими вещами для блока как margin, padding, border, position, float и т.д.???` - А как тогда? Силой мысли?

Comment: Действовать стоит по ситуации, как уже сказал @zhurof, не стоит придерживаться БЭМ'y на 100%.

Answer (score 1):

Используйте миксы. 
Смотрите: `.logo`,`.search` и `.auth` - блоки. Им позиционирование не задаём. Это позволяет без переопределения стилей использовать их в других местах на странице. Например, добавить `.logo` в подвал. 
Но если добавить к `.logo` класс `head__logo`, то получается элемент блока `.head`, который уже вовсю можно позиционировать

```css
.logo{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:blue;
}
.search{
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  background:red;
}
.auth{
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  background:green;
}
.head{
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid;
}
.head__logo{
  margin:0 20px 0 0;
}
.head__search{
  margin:0 auto 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
    <div class="logo head__logo"></div>
    <div class="search head__search"></div>
    <div class="auth head__auth"></div>
</div>
```

P.S. Совет: не стоит заморачиваться строгим соблюдением БЭМ в ущерб логике. Посмотрите на главной странице Яндекса, там даже наследование в селекторах есть.